# Data types of columns in DTS disconnected edit

Tags: sql-server, dts

When viewing a DTS package via Disconnected Edit, Destination or Source Columns within a Transform Data Task have a DataType property with values like 129, 130, 131, 135.

Where can I find a list of what these values mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's [DataTypeEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675318.aspx) of OLE DB types.